# ImageView with Rounded Corners

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-view, android-image

i have Created a Custom Image View Class that has rounded corner as given below

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {

public static float radius = 18.0f;  

public CustomImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //float radius = 36.0f;  
    Path clipPath = new Path();
    RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    clipPath.addRoundRect(rect, radius, radius, Path.Direction.CW);
    canvas.clipPath(clipPath);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

}

and

```
 <packagename.CustomImageView
            android:id="@+id/selectIcon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

CustomImageView  iconImage = (CustomImageView )findViewById(R.id.selectIcon);
iconImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.thumview);
```

Now the problem is that this image view works for some devices(like for Samsung pocket). While for some other devices it doesn't work. That is don't get rounded corners around the image view (like in xolo Q700).

Can Anyone please tell me what can be the issue?
Thank you

Comment: Check : https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView

Comment: use ImageView  iconImage = (ImageView )findViewById(R.id.selectIcon);